# Вопрос про профиль: могу ли я написать, что ищу работу?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, правила

Уважаемые более опытные участники,

я сейчас нахожусь в процессе поиска работы. А информация "обо мне" в профиле у меня не заполнена.

Мне показалось, что если я размещу в своём профиле информацию о том, что ищу работу, то могу получить полезные предложения. А мои "ответы на вопросы" могут служить некой первичной характеристикой меня как специалиста.

Не будет ли такое заполнение информации в профиле нарушением правил сайта?

я почитал другие сообщения в форуме, найденные по слову "работа", но никакого похожего вопроса - ответа не нашел.

Буду благодарен Вам за разъяснения.

Comment: Некоторые, как я замечал, пишут, и раз ничего в их профиле со временем не меняется, то это безопасно. А вы в каком городе и какой области IT хотели бы ее найти?

Comment: @avp - добрый вечер. спасибо за Ваш комментарий. Я ищу работу в Москве, у меня есть некоторый опыт в C# и "сопутствующих технологиях": С++, базы данных, server side и т.п. Хотел бы продолжить набираться опыта. Но пробелов в моих знаниях тоже хватает :-)

Comment: Я в [Baikal Electronics](https://www.baikalelectronics.ru/contacts/) (тут карта) работаю в Зеленограде. В принципе, нам нужны программисты (на Си). Если вам эта область и месторасположене (посмотрите на нашем сайте подробнее) интересны, то я буду там во вторник и поговорю с шефом, спрошу как лучше действовать,  заслать резюме через отдел кадров или напрямую.

Comment: О, а я про вас (про Байкал Электроникс) на хабре читал! По моему, у вас довольно много системного программирования и адаптации опенсорсного софта на специализированные процессоры. Думаю,можно в "первом раунде" обменяться мессенджерами (мой - https://t.me/konst_dav ) и пообщаться чуть подробнее. Но,я бы предложил сделать это уже завтра, ну или когда удобно - а то день был длинный

Comment: Ок. Дввайте завтра попереписываемся

Comment: По-моему не должно быть никаких препятствий для указания в профиле того, что вы ищете работу. У меня просто телеграм в профиле указан(он больше для участников) и рекрутеры периодически стучатся и спрашивают.

Comment: Хотя когда указываешь телеграм,  то нужно быть готовым к тому, что могут и школьники в час ночи стучаться  с просьбой помочь minecraft сервер поднять)))

Comment: @МихаилРебров - спасибо, тогда так и сделаю. Также, думаю, рекрутеры - это скорее "холодные звонки": посредники между мной и работодателем. как правило, их оценка (для чего я подхожу или не подхожу работодателю) не очень точна.

Comment: @S.H. , безусловно холодные. Но я себе и цели поиска нового места не ставил. И стоит признать, предложения ко мне не такие уж и плохие прилетали, от лидеров рынка.

Comment: А вообще `LinkedIn`, заблокированный РосКомНадзором тоже неплохая вещь. Ну и `HH` тот же никто не отменял. Ну и самому тоже не грех куда-нибудь постучаться. Главное не сильно торопиться (если условия позволяют) и найти то, что самому нравится.

Comment: @МихаилРебров - да, всё этот так. По hh.ru я всё время отслеживаю предложения. Но, надо сказать, процесс поиска сотрудников сильно заточен на то, что специалисты - кадровики сами находят кандидатов и связываются с ними. А для выхода на linkedin у меня недостаточный уровень устного английского

Comment: @S.H. в данном случае я предлагал рассматривать `LinkedIn` как инструмент для поиска работы в русскоязычной среде. Им рекрутеры очень даже пользуются при поиске разработчиков. Описание профиля и резюме можно и на русском составить. Большинство так и делает. Правда там немалый смысл в связях и контактах. Но мне кажется что найдутся в вашем окружении те, кто им также пользуются

Comment: @S.H., если честно, что-то мне лень ставить и осваивать telegram. Предпочитаю обычный email. Если хотите, напишите мне `avp210159@gmail.com`

Comment: @avp - нет проблем! Постараюсь за эти выходные написать! Спасибо!

Comment: @S.H., передумали или я неверный адрес email написал?

Comment: @avp - приветсвую! Нет,я не передумал, просто уже пару дней пытаюсь в голове уложить свой опыт и как то его сформулировать...  я напишу, пускай коротко, но уже сегодня вечером!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Безусловно, в своём профиле можно указывать информацию о поиске работы. Это не нарушает правил сайта. Достаточно посмотреть хотя бы на результаты следующих запросов:

- [looking for a job](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers%20looking%20for%20a%20job)
- [ищу работу](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers%20%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83)
- [моё резюме](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5)

При этом на большом Stack Overflow есть ещё и [специальный раздел](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/create), где можно сообщить о своём статусе по поиску работы.